# How to access Spring RequestContext from a Freemarker TemplateDirectiveModel

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I'm using Spring MVC with Freemarker as view technologie. I have a TemplateDirectiveModel object which needs to access Spring's RequestContext within the execute method. Currently I do it like this:

```
public class MyDirective implements TemplateDirectiveModel
{
    public void execute(Environment env, Map params, TemplateModel[] loopVars,
        TemplateDirectiveBody body) throws TemplateException, IOException
    {
        StringModel model = (StringModel) env.getGlobalVariable("springMacroRequestContext");
        RequestContext requestContext = (RequestContext) model.getWrappedObject();
    }
}
```

But I can't believe that this is the right way to do it. I have the feeling I missed something important. Maybe there are special classes and annotations for handling Freemarker direcives in Spring? Maybe I can let Spring inject something into the directive class with which I can access Springs request scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subclass `FreeMarkerConfigurer`, overriding its `postProcessConfiguration(Configuration config)`method.
Your implementation would just put a request-aware dependency in the configuration, as a [shared variable](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/freemarker/pgui_config_sharedvariables.html) for example (as preconised by the [FM documentation](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/freemarker/pgui_datamodel_directive.html)).

Should do the trick, Spring-style...

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this.  If you are already using spring's  FreeMarkerConfigurer, you can hand it a map of variables:

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer" 
p:templateLoaderPath="/some_path_here">
    <property name="freemarkerVariables">
        <map>
            <entry key='macroName' value-ref="templateModelRef" />
        </map>  
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="templateModelRef" class="...class..extends TemplateModel">
    <property name="someResource" value-ref="resourceRef"/>
</bean>
```

Now at least in a class that extends TemplateDirectiveModel's execute method you have access to that injected property.

```
public class MyDirective extends TemplateDirectiveModel {
    private MyResource someResource;
    @Override
    public void execute(Environment env, Map params, TemplateModel[] loopVars,TemplateDirectiveBody body) throws TemplateException, IOException {

        StringModel sharedVariable = (StringModel)env.getConfiguration().getSharedVariable("beanName");
        MyClass sweetness = (MyClass)sharedVariable.getWrappedObject();
    }       
}
```

Now in your .ftl you can use:

<@macroName />

and it will have spring dependencies auto injected.